# KnockoutJS Observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I am working with Knockout for the first time and I am struggling with an observable. I have declared it in one view model and I need to gain access to the value in another. Any tips on how to go about that?

Comment: Do you have any example code you can show?

Comment: Generally, just `firstModel.someObservable()` (assuming your second viewmodel knows about the first), but without a lot more context it's hard to advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do, it's to inherit the `parentViewModel`

```
 function parentViewModel() {
    // Just a best practice potato here :P
    var self = this;

    // Initialize the childViewModel change it's 'this'
    childViewModel.call(self);

    self.observable = ko.observable();
}

function childViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    console.log(self); // It will output the parentViewModel scope
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare your 1st model in a shared scope, then the 2nd. If you do something like `myfirstmodel.myobservable()` within your second model, you should see it and interact with it.

```
var myModel = whatever();
var mySndModel = whateverElse();

ko.applyBindings(myModel, document.getElementById('whatever'))
ko.applyBindings(mySndModel, document.getElementById('whateverElse'))
```

`whateverElse` is the constructor of your second model, in which you can call `myModel.myObservable()`